# Client Not Connecting with Mode Encrpyt and Sign And Algorithm is Basic256

Tags: opc-ua

```
var securityPolicy = new OpcSecurityPolicy(OpcSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt,OpcSecurityAlgorithm.Basic256Sha256);
var client = new OpcClient("opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49321", securityPolicy);
client.Security.UserIdentity = new OpcClientIdentity("Administrator", "R@12345678") ;
 client.Connect();
```

Error is:

> Error establishing a connection: Error received from remote host: An error occurred verifying security.

I need to make connections with kep server but its throwing error